# Mysqld not starting in XAMPP

Tags: mariadb

When I try to start mysql in XAMPP, the service briefly starts then stops unexpectedly after a few seconds. The mysql_error log doesn't show anything abnormal that I can see (see further down), but the Windows event viewer reports a number of issues.

XAMPP version 3.2.4 with built in mariaDB, port 3308 (tried 3306 & 3307 with similar or worse outcomes: I was able to manually start msqld.exe through windows explorer, the service showed as running in XAMPP but HeidiSQL became unresponsive when trying to connect to the server)

Any suggestions on how to fix this would be much appreciated.

Event viewer errors:

```
Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Incorrect file format 'db'

Aborting

mysqld.exe: Error writing file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\aria_log_control' (Errcode: 9 "Bad file descriptor")

mysqld.exe: Aria engine: checkpoint failed

mysqld.exe: Error writing file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\aria_log_control' (Errcode: 9 "Bad file descriptor")

mysqld.exe: Error on close of 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\aria_log_control' (Errcode: 9 "Bad file descriptor")


Mysql_Error log extract:

2023-06-10 10:32:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions

2023-06-10 10:32:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes

2023-06-10 10:32:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11

2023-06-10 10:32:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1

2023-06-10 10:32:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions

2023-06-10 10:32:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M

2023-06-10 10:32:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool

2023-06-10 10:32:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence number 38297845790 in the system tablespace does not match the log sequence number 38297845799 in the ib_logfiles!

2023-06-10 10:32:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.

2023-06-10 10:32:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"

2023-06-10 10:32:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables

2023-06-10 10:32:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...

2023-06-10 10:32:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.

2023-06-10 10:32:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start

2023-06-10 10:32:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.13 started; log sequence number 38297845799; transaction id 2864880

2023-06-10 10:32:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool

2023-06-10 10:32:23 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.

2023-06-10 10:32:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 230610 10:32:23

2023-06-10 10:32:23 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Comment: You have mariadb, not mysql. No  the two are not the same. For example, mysql does not have the aria table engine referenced by the error.

Comment: Thank you for updating the tag. I have however re-added XAMPP as it is relevant to the issue. I was on one occasion able to start mysqld.exe manually in the windows explorer, but I was unable to connect to it in any way (be it with HeidiSQL or with an app that accesses a database in MariaDB.

Comment: If I start XAMPP as administrator, it is able to start MariaDB, however, the Admin tool is unable to connect to the database:

mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

 Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.

I searched my.ini for "controluser" and could not find an entry.

I tried copying the data files to another instance of MariaDB but I am getting the error "table does not exist in engine.

Any suggestion to recover those tables would be much appreciated.

Comment: Xampp is absolutely irrelevant as it installs a standalone mariadb instance, nothing more. The question you asked about recovering data has already been answered on SO quite a few times...

Comment: I did not find the answers you are referring to. Most advise to use PHPmyadmin to create a new user...etc, but I have the same issue with PHPmyadmin. If you are not willing/able to help, then don't bother responding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to resolve the issue with MariaDB being inaccessible, however, I did find a way to recover the data:

1. install a new instance of the same version of XAMPP and make sure you select a new destination folder
2. make sure everything works (mostly Apache & MySQL should start and stay active, and PHPmyAdmin should start and not produce any error)
3. copy the folder where your data is located (typically \XAMPP\mysql\data<databaseName>) to the Data folder under the new XAMPP instance (e.g. c:\XAMPP2\MySQL\data)
4. copy the file ibdata1 from the original XAMPP MySQL\data folder under the new instance, same folder
5. open the new XAMPP instance and fire up Apache and MySQL (that is how it is labelled, I do NOT mean it *is* MySQL...)
6. the data should be accessible to view and export, or be used in the new instance

It isn't the perfect solution as it may require extensive reconfiguration of XAMPP components, but at least you have regained access to the data.